# exporting a class in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I have written three functions as below. I have clubbed amp.js and dish.js in one package.

amp.js:

```
var amp = (function() {
  //return ("This is a message from the demo package");

  function amp(){
      this.id=10;
  }
  amp.prototype.display=function(){  
      return 'value of id is';
  } 

}());

exports.amp =amp;
```

dish.js:

```
var cc=require('./amp');
exports.amp=cc.amp;
```

EX.js:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var just=require('JUST');
console.log(just);
var amp= new just.amp();
console.log(amp);
//var ww=new builder.ConsoleConnector();

// Create bot and bind to console
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', function(session){
    session.send("hello this is chat bot");
    //session.send("string returned from the %s",just.amp.display);
});
```

Here in EX.js I am trying to access the amp.js as a class constructor, i am getting the following error,

```
E:\bot-prac\EX.js:4
var amp= new just.amp();
         ^

TypeError: just.amp is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\bot-prac\EX.js:4:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Comment: What is `JUST` package? `var just=require('JUST');` it should be `./dish`?

Comment: JUST is a package consisting of just.js and dish.js. Main function in the package is dish.js

Comment: then JUST not exporting dish.js content, at least try to separately require `var dish = require('./dish')` that way you will know that dish.js is ok

Comment: What are you trying to do with amp? It is undefined...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to store utility/helper functions in an external file, then load and use them in your main app.js code.

```
// contents of utils.js
module.exports = {
  init: function() {
    // do initialization things here
  },
  makeSandwich: function() {
    // make sandwich code here
  },
  orderPizza: function(options) {
    // order pizza with options code here
  }
}
// END utils.js

// contents of app.js
var utils = require('./utils');

utils.init(); // call the init function
utils.makeSandwich() // call the make sandwich function

var pizzaOptions = {
  toppings: ['pepperoni', 'mushrooms', 'onions', 'olives'],
  cheese: 'Mozzerella',
  crust: 'Italian'
}

utils.orderPizza(pizzaOptions);
// END app.js
```

For more information, read the [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) core documentation.

Comment: Can it is possible use the makeSandwich function in same utils.js file.